# Find all localizations of $M=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ as a $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to find all localizations of $M=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ as a $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$-module.

---

Proposition (3.3) at Atiyah and MacDonald's commutative algebra states that the operation $S^{-1}$ is exact. So we have this propsition:

Proposition (3.3.1)': Let $R$ be an unital commutative ring, let $I \lhd R$ be an ideal in $R$, and let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$. Let $\bar{S}$ denote the image of $S$ in the quotient ring $\bar{R}=R/I$. Applying the proposition (3.3), to the exact sequence $0 \longrightarrow I \longrightarrow R \longrightarrow R/I \longrightarrow 0$, we get that: $\bar{S}^{-1}\bar{R} = S^{-1}R/IS^{-1}R$.

---

Suppose that $p$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=n\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\{ 1, p, p^2, \cdots, p^t,  \cdots \}$. Also, assume that $n=p^e\times m$, where $\gcd(m, n)=1$.

Then $S^{-1}R=S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]=\oplus_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}p^{-i}$.

---

> My Question is: (A): Why $I(S^{-1}R) = m\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$? (B): Why $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]}{m\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]}=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$?

---

I guess (I am not sure, **Could you please help me to understand it clearly**?) that $I(S^{-1}R)$ should be equal to $m\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$ (Since $p^e$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$). So for $M=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ as a $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$-module, we have $\bar{S}^{-1}{M} = \dfrac{S^{-1}R}{I(S^{-1}R)} = \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]}{m\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]}=(^*_*\rm I \ don't \ know \ how, \ but \ I \ guess \ that^*_*)=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$.

---

**Final result**: So if we have the prime factorization of $n=p_1^{\alpha_1} \times \cdots \times p_j^{\alpha_j}$, then depending on whether we want $p_i$ be invertible in localization or not, the expression $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p_i^{\alpha_i}\mathbb{Z}}$ will be deleted or remain in the final result, respectively. In other words, if we write $\{1, 2, \cdots, j  \}$ as a disjoint union $K \dot\bigcup L$ such that, (1): [for any $k\in K$, $S$ contatins a multiple of $p_k$], and (2): [for any $l\in L$, $S$ does not contatin a multiple of $p_l$]; then $\bar{S}^{-1}{M} = \oplus_{l \in L} \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p_l^{\alpha_l}\mathbb{Z}}$. So we have exactly $2^j$ different localiztions for $M=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$.