# About the module structure of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $m, n$ be arbitrary natural numbers. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and let $S=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

For which values we can equip $S$ with an $R$-module structure?

---

I know that if $m \mid n$, then the multiplication by $\dfrac{n}{m}$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to itself, and the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ as a group.

This map does not preserve multiplication, and so this map is not a ring homomorphism. How should I prove that there is not any ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, for $m\neq n$?

I don't have any idea about the module structure.

Comment: Your question is stated as an isolated problem without context or effort of your own. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your question accordingly. It is likely to attract down votes and get closed.

Comment: @Christoph What explanations should I add to my question? I don't have any idea what should I do, with this problem. Please see the last two questions. (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841385/find-all-localizations-of-m-dfrac-mathbbzn-mathbbz-as-a-dfrac-math (2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840241/localization-of-some-modules

Comment: Do you know what an $R$-module is? Do you see that the action of $1_R$ on $1_S$ completely defines the module structure in this particular case? What choices of $1_R\cdot 1_S$ lead to well defined module structures?

Comment: @Christoph I edited my question right now. Is it good? I can change it in the way that you want. I know what an $R$-module is. I think the only choice for $1_R.1_S$ is $1_S$, am I mistaken? But I can't realize why "the action of $1_R$ on $1_S$, completely defines the module structure"? You are not speaking with friendly phrases.

Comment: For example $2_R\cdot 3_S = (1_R+1_R)\cdot(1_S+1_S+1_S) = 1_R\cdot 1_S + 1_R\cdot 1_S + 1_R\cdot 1_S + 1_R\cdot 1_S + 1_R\cdot 1_S + 1_R\cdot 1_S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then
$$
(0+n\Z)(1+m\Z)=0+m\Z,
$$
but also
$$
(0+n\Z)(1+m\Z)=(n+n\Z)(1+m\Z)=n[(1+n\Z)(1+m\Z)]=n(1+m\Z)=n+m\Z.
$$
So $0+m\Z=n+m\Z$, that tells you that $m$ divides $n$, say $n=mk$. So this is necessary.

Now, we show that $m$ divides $n$ is sufficient. In order to prove that $\Z/m\Z$ is a $\Z/n\Z$-module we need to verify

1. $(a+b)x=ax+bx$
2. $a(x+y)=ax+ay$
3. $a(bx)=(ab)x$
4. $1x=x$

for all $a,b\in\Z/n\Z$ and all $x,y\in\Z/m\Z$.
But if $a=a'$ (mod $n$), then $a-a'=nt=mkt$, and so $a=a'$ (mod $m$). From this fact 1), 2) and 3) are true because $\Z/m\Z$ is a ring. 4) is also trivially true.

In conclusion $\Z/m\Z$ is a $\Z/n\Z$-module iff $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: The answer is surprising to me, because I think there is no ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. (Is it correct?) If we consider this question for group homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ as groups, then the answer will be "If and only if $m \mid n$ or $n \mid m$"? (Is it correct?)

Comment: I think I was mistaken. Let $d=\gcd(n,m)$, then both of $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$ have a subgroup which is isomorphic to $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{d\mathbb{Z}}$. Now we can map $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{d'\mathbb{Z}}$, for any divisor $d' \mid d$. So I think the answer to the last question is "there is a nontrivial group homomorphism between them, if and only if $\gcd(m,n) > 1$, and all the maps have this form".

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer by @AntonioFicarra we know that "if $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $m \mid n$.

Note that if $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ is an $A$-module. suppose that $m \mid n$, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module. Now note that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, so we can conclude that $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module.